# Shell_exec issue with php

Tags: php, linux, exec, restart, shell-exec

I got a small issue with shell_exec function.
What I'm trying to do is restart linux server by clicking on a button. I can't, however, seem to get the command to work.

This is the command I'm trying to use:

```
shell_exec('sudo sbin/shutdown -r now');
```

I've been reading about this issue for some hours now and tried all I could find but to no avail.

So here's what I've tried:
First of all, I checked that there's no line in php.ini to prevent me from using the command.
Secondly, I added this line to /etc/sudoers

```
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

When that didn't work either, I also created a new file to  etc/sudoers.d/ and wrote this there: `%users ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown`

Also I don't know if that's relevant or not but when I tried to run another shell_exec in that very same place, it works fine (returns www-data) as

```
echo shell_exec("whoami");
```

But shows nothing when I add sudo:

```
echo shell_exec("sudo whoami");
```

So yeah, if there's anyone who can tell me what else to try, I would appreciate that. Thanks in advance. PS, It's linux wheezy that I'm trying to get this to work on if that's of any help.

Edit: even `nobody ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`
 in sudoers file doesn't seem to make my shell_exec work with sudo.

Comment: From : http://codebin.co.uk/blog/running-scripts-as-root-from-php/ : if the output is empty and the command silently fails, it’s because sudo is set to only be used directly from the terminal. Solution in link (haven't tested it don't know if it works).

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a typo maybe.

It should be `shell_exec('sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now');`, using relative paths won't work everytime.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I also checked php.ini files to see if sudo was disabled and that wasn't the case either. Truth being told, I tried so many different things I can't even recall them all anymore (basically everything that comes up when you google sudo and shell_exec problems) but so far nothing has worked.